# How can I return the list of rows meeting a certain condition with the row just before it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, subquery

```
precise_value_date          local_limit_amount
2020-12-10 18:45:37.650     1800000.000000
2020-12-18 19:01:09.530     3225000.000000
2020-12-31 00:00:00.000     1800000.000000
2021-01-18 00:00:00.000     2300000.000000
2021-04-27 00:00:00.000     1500000.000000
2021-07-22 00:00:00.000     500000.000000
2021-08-31 00:00:00.000     500000.000000
2021-12-31 00:00:00.000     0.000000
```

I want to return all of the rows beyond today's date as well as the last one
Meaning if today is 2020-12-24 00:00:00.000
I will be receiving all of the data after that date as well as the one row just before it
so the fetched data will be as follows:

```
precise_value_date          local_limit_amount
2020-12-18 19:01:09.530     3225000.000000
2020-12-31 00:00:00.000     1800000.000000
2021-01-18 00:00:00.000     2300000.000000
2021-04-27 00:00:00.000     1500000.000000
2021-07-22 00:00:00.000     500000.000000
2021-08-31 00:00:00.000     500000.000000
2021-12-31 00:00:00.000     0.000000
```

If today's date happens to be in one of the fetched data I will only return the ones >= to it and not the last row
Meaning if today is 2021-04-27 00:00:00.000 the table will be as follows:

```
precise_value_date          local_limit_amount
2021-04-27 00:00:00.000     1500000.000000
2021-07-22 00:00:00.000     500000.000000
2021-08-31 00:00:00.000     500000.000000
2021-12-31 00:00:00.000     0.000000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(precise_value_date) over (order by precise_value_date) as next_precise_value_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_precise_value_date is null or
      next_precise_value_date >= curdate()
order by precise_value_date;
```

Or, you can use `union all`:

```
select x.*
from ((select top (1) t.*
       from t
       where t.precise_value_date < convert(date, getdate())
       order by t.precise_value_date desc
      ) union all
      (select t.*
       from t
       where t.precise_value_date >= convert(date, getdate())
      )
     ) x;
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax keeps appearing next to the Limit 1
 select *
from (
    select * from #temp7 where precise_value_date < GETDATE()
    union all
    (select * from #temp7 where precise_value_date >= GETDATE() order by precise_value_date limit 1)
) t
order by precise_value_date

I am using SQL Server 2018

Comment: A small rectification on the operators made it work!

This query is now functional

select *
from (
    select * from mytable where precise_value_date >= convert(date, getdate())
    union all
    (select top (1) * from mytable where precise_value_date < convert(date, getdate()) order by precise_value_date)
) t
order by precise_value_date

Thanks a lot

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi . . . Your question was originally tagged MySQL, which is why I used `limit`.  I fixed the answer for SQL Server.

Comment: The DESC should be added to the top 1 order by as well
since we're bringing the last row before the current date 
Thanks again!

select * from ( select * from mytable where precise_value_date >= convert(date, getdate()) union all (select top (1) * from mytable where precise_value_date < convert(date, getdate()) order by precise_value_date DESC) ) t order by precise_value_date

Answer (score 1):

This looks like `union all`:

```
select *
from (
    select * from mytable where precise_value_date < current_date
    union all
    (select * from mytable where precise_value_date >= current_date order by precise_value_date limit 1)
) t
order by precise_value_date
```

In MySQL, the outer `select` is not even necessary:

```
select * from mytable where precise_value_date < current_date
union all
(select * from mytable where precise_value_date >= current_date order by precise_value_date limit 1)
order by precise_value_date
```

In SQL Server:

```
select *
from (
    select * from mytable where precise_value_date < convert(date, getdate())
    union all
    (select top (1) * from mytable where precise_value_date >= convert(date, getdate()) order by precise_value_date)
) t
order by precise_value_date
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax keeps appearing next to the Limit 1
 select *
from (
    select * from #temp7 where precise_value_date < GETDATE()
    union all
    (select * from #temp7 where precise_value_date >= GETDATE() order by precise_value_date limit 1)
) t
order by precise_value_date

I am using SQL Server 2018

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi: then why did you tag the question MySQL? This is a different product than SQL Server. Anyway, see my update.

Comment: my bad!
This query is now functional
select *
from (
    select * from mytable where precise_value_date >= convert(date, getdate())
    union all
    (select top (1) * from mytable where precise_value_date < convert(date, getdate()) order by precise_value_date)
) t
order by precise_value_date

Thanks a lot